# In rails link is redirecting to SHOW instead of DESTROY

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

Destroy in respective controller

```
def destroy
  if GovtSubsidy.find(params[:id]).destroy 
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
    flash[:success] = "Successfully Deleted!"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Sorry! Could not complete the request, please try again!"
    redirect_to :action => 'index'
  end
end
```

This is the index.html.erb

```
       <% @govtsubsidy.each do |f| %>
        <tr>

            <td><%= f.id %></td>
            <td><%= f.society.name %></td>
            <td><%= f.opening_balance %></td>
            <td><%= f.recieved_balance %></td>
            <td><%= f.total_oustanding %></td>

            <td>
                <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-edit'></span>".html_safe,   edit_admin_govt_subsidy_path(f) %>
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= link_to "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>".html_safe, admin_govt_subsidy_path(f), :method => :delete, :title => "Delete Government Assistance Category", "data-confirm" => "Do you really want to delete?" %>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
```

In routes.rb

```
          resources :govt_subsidies
```

In rake routes

```
 admin_govt_subsidies GET    /admin/govt_subsidies(.:format)                                          admin/govt_subsidies#index
                                      POST   /admin/govt_subsidies(.:format)                                     admin/govt_subsidies#create
                 new_admin_govt_subsidy GET    /admin/govt_subsidies/new(.:format)                        admin/govt_subsidies#new
              edit_admin_govt_subsidy GET    /admin/govt_subsidies/:id/edit(.:format)                   admin/govt_subsidies#edit
                   admin_govt_subsidy GET    /admin/govt_subsidies/:id(.:format)                        admin/govt_subsidies#show
                                      PATCH  /admin/govt_subsidies/:id(.:format)                        admin/govt_subsidies#update
                                      PUT    /admin/govt_subsidies/:id(.:format)                        admin/govt_subsidies#update
                                      DELETE   /admin/govt_subsidies/:id(.:format)                          admin/govt_subsidies#destroy
```

EDIT - rendered html for the delete link

```
<a data-confirm="Do you really want to delete?" 
   data-method="delete" 
   href="/admin/govt_subsidies/2" 
   rel="nofollow" 
   title="Delete Government Assistance Category">
     <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span>
</a>
```

Javascript included already . Here are all the javascript file that are being included. Some are being repeated . Is thats why js files are conflicting and request going to GET instead of DESTROY

```
      <link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
       <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:600,400,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery-ui/theme.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery-ui/core.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/normalize.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/bootstrap.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/main.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/tabs.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/tabstyles.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/style.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />
<link data-turbolinks-track="true" href="/assets/application.css?body=1" media="all" rel="stylesheet" />

  <script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turnBox.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/main.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/retina.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/bootstrap.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.easing.1.3.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/smoothscroll.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-func.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/dots.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/modernizr-2.6.2.min.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/turbolinks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/core.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery-ui/datepicker.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1"></script>
**<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1"></script>**
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/dataTables/jquery.dataTables.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/dataTables/bootstrap/3/jquery.dataTables.bootstrap.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/data-confirm-modal.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/taluks.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/ceos.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/progress_charters.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/societies.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin-layout.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/a_class_members.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/a_class_reserved_counts.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/a_class_type_counts.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/accrued_funds.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/annual_general_bodies.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/assettypes.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/b_government_members.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/bordelection_dates.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/borrowings.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/branches.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/c_nominal_members.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/collected_deposits.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/d_associate_members.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/dashboard.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/dcb_all_loans.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/detail_of_directors.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/election_dates.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/employee_counts.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/establishment_details.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/goverment_assistances.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/government_assistance_categories.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/govt_loans.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/govt_subsidies.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/investments.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/loan_advance_categories.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/major_activities.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/non_credit_businesses.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/owned_assets.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/rented_assets.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/self_helf_groups.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/self_help_groups.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/social_activities.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/society_assets.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/society_category.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/society_status.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/users.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/villages.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/yashashwini_health_scheme.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/admin/yashaswini_health_schemes.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/annual_general_bodies.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/cbpFWTabs.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/election_dates.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/index.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/interact.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/modernizr.custom.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/npm.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/plugins.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/societies.js?body=1"></script>
<script data-turbolinks-track="true" src="/assets/application.js?body=1"></script>
```

Comment: Make sure your javascripts are working.

Comment: Thanks for the reply .Other all links are working .. getting destroyed also

Comment: Can you add the rendered html for the delete link to your post please?

Comment: Can you try running this `rake assets:clean`

Comment: Hi @Sontya I tried that command.. restarted rails server. Still no help

Comment: @Max Williams Rendered HTML:                                                                  <td><a data-confirm="Do you really want to delete?" data-method="delete" href="/admin/govt_subsidies/2" rel="nofollow" title="Delete Government Assistance Category"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-trash'></span></a>
</td>

Comment: I've added this to your post like i asked you to do -  if it's in a comment it's hard to read.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you forget to load `jquery-ujs` assets as recommended in [jquery-rails](https://github.com/rails/jquery-rails#installation) gem. [jquery-ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs) is [handle](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/blob/148571ded762f22ccca84db38d4b4d56853ab395/src/rails.js#L25) `data-method` attribute on client side and make correspond request type to server.

So, without it your link make GET request instead of DELETE.

[Here](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery#data-method-links-that-result-in-post-put-or-delete-requests) is more details.

Comment: Why are you loading jquery and jquery-ujs at the bottom of all JSs? Move them to top.